# windows phone 8 - can app disable buttons?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm not a WP8 dev, but I wanted to write a little timer app for my toddler. Thing is, she shouldn't be able to turn it off by clicking 'home','back' or 'search', but by password only. Its for personal use only, so store policies/hackiness dont matter. I know it can be done on android, but how about WP8?

Answer (score 0):

You could programatically block any back-button presses (though it's not compliant with windows phone store requirement), but there's no way to block start and search buttons.

Comment: Would it be possible to implement it as some sort of screen saver app?

Comment: you mean with the lockscreen?

Comment: @Kulasangar Yes, that's the word. My requirements are minimal: set a timer, press start. Be presented with a screen from which the only way out is some password or touch combo. The screen indicates progress in a toddler-understandable way. Do you think a lock screen could be used for that?

Comment: but i don't think you'll be able to manipulate lockscreen events, or even the start button as @lisp mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating those buttons with some `DuctTape`